# Why is the divs appearing vertically rather than horizontally?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my html. The style section is a bit different cause I am writting in React but otherwise I guess my problem is occuring because of the css and html. Why is the inner divs appearing in a lower row. I want it to appear horizontally inside the outer div with scrolling in x-axis. I already gave properties like white-space:nowrap.

```
 <div style={{position:'absolute', width:'1200px', height:'80px',background:'#cc5',top:'270px',left:'100px',whiteSpace: 'nowrap',display:'inline-block',overflowX:'auto'}}>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>

            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>


            <div style={{width:'100px',height:'60px',background:'white',display:'inline-block',margin:'10px',float:'left'}}></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the used style is React code and is translated to actual HTML in the browser?

Comment: yea that is for sure

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the style:

```
display:'inline-block'
```

Also your code block has problem, I fixed for two div below:

```html
<div style="position:absolute; width:1200px; height:80px;background:#cc5;top:270px;left:100px;whiteSpace: nowrap;display:block;'overflow-x':auto">
<div style="position:absolute; width:1200px; height:80px;background:#cc5;top:270px;left:100px;whiteSpace: nowrap;display:block;'overflow-x':auto">
```

Comment: Then what to use so that it doesn't come to new line

Comment: what to use then ... I changed it to inline but even that doesn't help

Comment: you can use display:block

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some modifications as below:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; width: 1200px; height: 80px;background: #cc5;top: 270px;left: 100px;white-space: nowrap;display: inline-block;overflow-x: auto;">
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 60px;background: white;display: inline-block;margin: 10px;float: left"></div>
</div>
```

Since you have inline style you can move them to css files. Also, `overflowX` needs to be changed to `overflow-x`

Comment: In react we write that way camelCase ...otherwise its just that same

Comment: @J.Doe You should add the proper tag to the question then. Just [css] is not enough: what you have there is not real css!

Comment: your code also generates the same result ...I mean in one row you have 9 white divs ..then 9 in next row and so on...what I want is just one row and all elements continue in one row ..and I get them when I scroll right @MrLister